# NGSI proxy wirecloud

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I have installed standalone version of wirecloud and ngsi-proxy using docker.While I am able to create subscriptions(able to view subscription id) I am unable to receive notifications from Orion Context Broker.What might be causing this? 
This is from where I downloaded image for ngsi-proxy.
https://github.com/conwetlab/ngsi-proxy/tree/develop/docker

Comment: Why are you "unable to receive notifications"? What does that mean?

Comment: whenever an attribute in an entity in the context broker changes it posts the changed value  which i am not being notified by ngsi proxy

Comment: Do you have more details? are you using the ngsi-source operator? what configuration? using another available ngsi proxy makes that configuration work?

Comment: I have a similar behavior from wire cloud page, but when I refresh the page, I get the new value. Did you find a solution?

Comment: try wirecloud docker